# VST on XCode 4.6 - Plugin gives high output directly when loaded

Tags: c++, vst

I'm programming a Steinberg VST-Plugin in XCode 4.6.

I've already implemented a Highpass-filter which works correctly. Now I'm trying to do some nonlinear distortion with a quadratic function. After I implemented the few lines below and loaded the plugin into the host, I get immediatly an Output from the plugin - you can hear nothing, but the meter is up high.

I really can't imagine why. The processReplacing function where the math takes place should only be called when playing sound, not when the plugin is loaded. When I remove the few lines of code below, everything is okay and sounds right, so I assume it has nothing to do with the rest of the plugin-code.

The problem takes place in two hosts, so its probably not a VST-bug.
Has anybody ever experienced a similar problem?

Many Thanks,
Fabian

```
void Exciter::processReplacing(float** inputs, float** outputs, VstInt32 sampleFrames){

  for(int i = 0; i < sampleFrames; i++) {

    tempsample = inputs[0][i];


//Exciter - Transformation in positive region, quadratic distortion and backscaling

    tempsample = tempsample + 1.0f;        
    tempsample = powf(tempsample, 2.0f);
    tempsample = tempsample / 2.0f;
    tempsample -= 1.0f;        


//Mix-Knob: Dry/Wet ------------------------------------------------

    outputs[0][i] = mix*(tempsample) + (1-mix)*inputs[0][i];
```

EDIT: I added logfile-outputs to each function and it occurs, that the processReplacing function is called permanently, not only when playback is turned on ... But why?

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much answered the question yourself with your edit.  `processReplacing` is called repeatedly.  This is part of the VST specification.

VST plug-ins are targeted for **real time** effects processing.  Don't confuse or misinterpret this as lookahead.  By real time, I mean inserting the plug-in into a channel and playing an instrument while the DAW is recording.  So you can see that in order to mitigate latency, the host is always sending the plug-in an audio buffer (whether it's silence or not).

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the processReplacing would be only called when the DAW does record and/or playback, but not when the DAW is stopped. Do you know what the DAW sends to the plugin, when playback/recording is stopped? A samplebuffer full of zeroes? Many Thanks, Fabian

Comment: Yes, it's a buffer full of zeroes.